# Python compiled .exe classed as virus

Tags: python

Python 3.65, Windows 7.

My antivirus (Avira) says my compiled code is a virus and keeps deleting it.
I have white-listed my program, but it worries me that 11 other virus checkers ou t of 60 on VirusTotal also think its a virus.

I am confident that it's a false positive but what about when I get to the point of writing something worth distributing?

Is this normal? Or is there something in my source code that looks "virusy" to heuristics when compiled?

```
import pyperclip
from tkinter import *
from ctypes import windll
import os
import time
# default folder for saves "c:\\cb-pastes"
#default txt file "c:\\cb-pastes\\saved.txt"
#================set up gui=======================
root = Tk()

#check if "c:\\cb-pastes" exists, if not, create folder
check_folder=os.path.isdir("c:\\cb-pastes")
if not check_folder:
    os.makedirs("c:\\cb-pastes")

#button functions
def call_save():
    ct=time.asctime()          #get system time and date in ct
    cb_txt = pyperclip.paste() #store clipboard in cb_txt

    f = open("c:\\cb-pastes\\saved.txt","a") # open the file:
    f.write ("\n")                           #newline
    f.write (ct)                             #save date and time with the text
    f.write ("\n")
    f.write (cb_txt)                         #append to text file      
    f.write ("\n")
    f.write ("-----------------------------")  
    f.close()                               #Close the file

def call_clear(): #clear clipboard
    if windll.user32.OpenClipboard(None):
        windll.user32.EmptyClipboard()
        windll.user32.CloseClipboard()


def call_view(): #open text file of saved clips
    os.startfile('c:\\cb-pastes\\saved.txt')

def call_viewcb(): #open text file of current clipboard contents
    cb_get = pyperclip.paste()
    f = open("c:\\cb-pastes\\temp.txt","w")
    f.write (cb_get)
    f.close()
    os.startfile('c:\\cb-pastes\\temp.txt')


#create window
root.title ("CBMan V0.8")
root.geometry ("230x132")

# create buttons
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

button1 = Button(app, text = "Save Clipboard",width=13, command=call_save)
button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
button2 = Button(app, text = "Clear Clipboard",width=13, command=call_clear)
button2.grid()
button3 = Button(app, text = "View Saves     ",width=13, command=call_view)
button3.grid()
button4 = Button(app, text = "View Clipboard ",width=13, command=call_viewcb)
button4.grid()

#insert logo
photo = PhotoImage(file="c:\\cb-pastes\\cbman.gif")
label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.grid(row=0,column=1)

mainloop()
```

Any advice please? Steve (It's a) Shambles.

Comment: To gather more information, try that: remove the ctypes import and the windll.user32 lines in your code. Recompile and see if the exe is thought to be a virus. Antiviruses use heuristic to detect if a file might be a new virus. It is possible that this access to clipboard is a frequent feature in known virus and that the antivirus is somehow able to detect it.

Comment: Link to the VirusTotal page for the sample you already submitted? It'd be helpful to get the exact signatures that are matching.

Comment: (There *are* viruses that'll infect newly-created executables; it's helpful to know if it's one of those for which you're being matched, which might mean that it's a true positive and your host is infected. Not the only or necessarily even most likely explanation, but not one worth discarding either).

Comment: Here's the link Charles:  https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/ed3610bf1e2f5199c5462498a794719b3347ef6b4779668d146165e5bda624cf/analysis/1529502718/  Now I will try @oliver Melancon suggestions.

Comment: I recompiled as per @Oliver Melancon instructions, exactly the same result with avira,

Comment: I turned off heuristics in Avira, recompiled and it still comes up as a virus, now I am getting worried, shall do full system scan.

Comment: Here is what Avira detects, it says it'sa special heuristic routine, yet I turned off H's and it still detects it.    https://www.avira.com/en/support-threats-summary-product?tid=147932&threat=HEUR&track=1    "A generic detection routine designed to detect common family characteristics shared in several variants. This special detection routine was developed in order to detect unknown variants and will be enhanced continuously."

Comment: In quarantine Avira now marks it as "clean", It's a ruddy shambles sir :-)  https://s22.postimg.cc/hciobvwcx/Region.png

Comment: ...looks like a bunch of executable-heuristic flags. Which is fair -- I don't know how any reasonable AV scanner could determine this (or almost any other py2exe-generated executable) *not* to be potential malware, since you've got dynamic invocation in play. The whole "let's look at library linking for things that are frequently put to malicious use" approach pretty much falls apart when you have code that can dynamically link and invoke (at the C level) pretty much anything. Same problem with C executables that use dlopen().

Comment: On the balance of probabilities would you say I'm not infected Charles?

Comment: Just to end this post. I sent Avira Labs my file and they passed it as "clean" https://s22.postimg.cc/8h95grbxt/clean.png

Comment: I had this issue a while ago using PyInstaller. Try other freezing methods to see if you get same result. I use cx_freeze and after a little issue with avast (wanting me to submit it before it would stop pestering me) it worked like a charm.